# Make two layouts share the same $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

I want to propose two layouts (ie, `horizontal` and `vertical`) for my contents. So switching in the selector will lead automatically to the corresponding layout. Here is the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hevutuweba/edit?html,output):

```
<html ng-app="flapperNews">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="horizontal.tpl">
        <textarea ng-model="one"></textarea>, <textarea ng-model="two"></textarea>
        <br><br>{{one}}+{{two}}
    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="vertical.tpl">
        <textarea ng-model="one"></textarea><br><textarea ng-model="two"></textarea>
        <br><br>{{one}}+{{two}}
    </script>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('entry', {
                url: '/',
                params: { tpl: 'vertical' },
                templateUrl: function (params) {
                  return params.tpl + ".tpl"
                }
            })
    }]);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
        $scope.one = "one";
        $scope.two = "two";
        $scope.layouts = ["horizontal", "vertical"];
        $scope.$watch('layout', function () {
          $state.go('entry', {tpl: $scope.layout});
        })
    }])
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <select ng-model="layout" ng-init="layout = 'horizontal' || layouts[0].value" ng-options="x for x in layouts"></select>
    <br><br>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>

</html>
```

However, with the above code, each time we change the view, `$scope.one` and `$scope.two` are reset to their initial values. I would hope the change in their textarea would remain regardless of the change of layout.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy sharing same data between different views by using `factories` ([AngularJS factory documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)). Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3u6op7hx/2/), it uses a simple factory named `myFactory` to share data between controllers. This also does work on the same controller as in your case.

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[ "ui.router"]);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state("state1", {
        url: "#",
        template: '<p>{{ aValue }}</p><button ng-click="bindValue(\'its me\')">Bind value</button>',
        controller: "myController"
    }).state("state2", {
        url: "#",
        template: '<p>{{ aValue }}</p><button ng-click="bindValue(\'its me\')">Bind value</button>',
        controller: "myController"
    });
});


myApp.controller( "myController", function($scope, myFactory) {
    $scope.aValue = myFactory.myValue;

    $scope.bindValue = function (value) {
        $scope.aValue = value;
        myFactory.myValue = value;
    }
});


myApp.factory('myFactory', function () {
    return {
        myValue: ''
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <nav>
        <a ui-sref="state1">State 1</a>
        <a ui-sref="state2">State 2</a>
    </nav>
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the question is... should this business logic use one shared/parent controller or two controllers that communicate by a factory?

Comment: Depends on your application specs. I would use 2 controllers and put all shared functionalities into a factory to avoid redundancy. In that way your logic used in multiple controllers is capped in a nice factory and your controllers are still atomar.

Comment: I would prefer one shared controller, because I want switching among layouts to be only about the change of template, I don't want other things behind (eg, controller) to change...

Comment: Makes sense, as I said it depends on your specs. Keep in mind, in the moment you put logic in your controller which is only used in one layout -> your argument is obsolete. You could still use this example for one controller. Do I need to create an example where only one controller is used?

Comment: Yes, I would prefer one controller+two templates that can really naturally share variable values between them...

Comment: It works... Here is [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/wujikewuhi/1/edit?html,output) as a record...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use  [nested](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views) views - you can define main controller on parent route state and define two nested states corresponding to two views. This way parent controller will remain (it's not re-initialised when child states are switched) and only nested states views will be changed. Something like this:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('myState', {
    url: '/test/',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: function() {
        //main controller shared by child states
        ...
    }
  })
  .state('myState.view1', {
    url: '/test/view1'
    templateUrl: 'tpl-1.hmtl',
    ...
  })
  .state('myState.view2', {
    url: '/test/view2'
    templateUrl: 'tpl-2.hmtl',
    ...
  })
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? One thing I want to avoid (and I don't know how) is to define two views in the same template, and to **HIDE** one according to the choice of the layout. I don't like the idea of **HIDE**.